# Why if (arg0.length > 0 && arg0[0].equals("exitcode"))?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I found this SpringBoot Application code which throws Exit Code 10 when executed with argument "exitcode".

```
public class Swagger2SpringBoot implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        if (arg0.length > 0 && arg0[0].equals("exitcode")) {
            throw new ExitException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(SpringBootEntityApp.class).run(args);
    }

    class ExitException extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return 10;
        }

    }

}
```

Running this code with the given argument exits the program.

```
java -jar exitcode arg1 arg2
```

I would be grateful if somebody could explain the use-case of this code.

**PS:**
Why are we running the program to exit the program.

**References:**

1. [Swagger Petstore](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/server/petstore/springboot/src/main/java/io/swagger/Swagger2SpringBoot.java).
2. [Plaza Client](https://gitlab.psb.ugent.be/PLAZA/plaza-api-clients/blob/95950e8faed5766fa94a161614d7b9554038cbc5/clients/spring/src/main/java/io/swagger/Swagger2SpringBoot.java)
3. [Yidi](http://139.159.188.44/xujunxiong/yidi/blob/938b5c19346de598e601d028e0d80ff4e2b5f1d3/code/ecp-parent/ecp-order/src/main/java/com/isurein/ecp/order/OrderApplication.java)
4. [Stack Overflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783858/springboot-with-hibernate-internal-server-error-but-status-code-200)
5. [Docker Dash](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=petrleocompel/docker-dash/docker-dash-master/server/src/main/java/cz/plc/prx/docker/dash/DockerDashApp.java)

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: You should probably be asking the author why they wrote such code. It looks like someone was just writing a "hello world" app for spring

Comment: @ScaryWombat : What is the use-case?

Comment: @smac89 There are many places, this code snippet is used. The reference link is updated.

Comment: Now that is peculiar indeed

Comment: It looks like it is code generated by swagger command line. Go to page 49 of [this](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oraclecode17/sess/1487918145688001oiCo/PF/API%20First%20Strategy_v1_1_YG_KIM_1504243296065001FtCj.pdf) pdf and start scrolling forward from there. And [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/pull/82/files#) looks like the PR that introduced it to swagger